# Jquery takes last output as value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some code and it is for sending comments to database.
And I have jquery and ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


            $('#comm1').keypress(function(event) {

            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {

                 var comment = $('#comm1').val();
                var fromstatid = '<?php echo $status->fromid; ?>';
                var status = '<?php echo $status->id;?>';
                var fromid = '<?php echo $frid; ?>';

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "d/includes/counts.php",
                    data: {u: fromid, status: status, comment: comment, fus: fromstatid},
                    success: function(status) {

                        $('#comm1').val('');

                    }

                });
                };
            }); 

    });
</script>

#comm1 is textarea for comment ..
```

For php I have like basic output from database and the problem is that my jquery use only last output from database as value. In other words where ever I type a comment it send to database for the last output. It works if I have button for Reply and then it sends me to new page or something where I can limit output from database to 1 or to only that where I want to comment. But can I do it here on the page where are all comments... Also I was trying to set id as some word + php id from database for that output but it seem like when I add this to jquery code noting going to work....
The code I tried is : `$("#something<?php echo $status->id; ?>").keypress.....`
It stops the script it looks like the whole script is not working...

I asked similar question but no one answered me the right question... Also I was thinking of can I like make foreach in jquery here on this code.. And say for each output do something. I really don't know why it use only last output on page as value but it will help a lot if someone have some explanation?

EDITED:
Or do I need to echo for each output the jquery code?

UPDATE:
Tried by echoing the whole jquery code and it is not working....

NEW:
As you asked I have d/includes/counts.php file and the index.php

Inside counts.php i just input in database values send via ajax...
Inside index.php I said I have basic foreach database output to echo something like $status->text and for comment to echo textarea where I can type comment for text... Code is too long and I dont have problems with that code I have problems with connecting jquery code to all outputs not only last one....

---

Why does my `var status = '<?php echo $status->id; ?>';` AND `var fromstatid = '<?php echo $status->fromid; ?>';` use only last output values? Can I make some var inside echo for each output and use that var here in code to navigate which one is commented on?

I founded that also the script work only on one output like if I try to comment on the other one and press ENTER it wont work....

Answer (score 0):

You must know that only the last output of the PHP file will be retrieved. So I'm wondering what did you output in the PHP file ? Can you post the PHP code please ? (Sorry, for answering here but not enough points to comment).

Comment: I added by my output is just text for some post or something and textarea with name and id and it looks like this :
<textarea id='comm1'  name='comm1'   onkeyup='textAreaAdjust(this)' style=' resize: none; width: 300px; height: auto;'></textarea>

Comment: It works when I left id as comm1 but it saves values only for last output and when I change it with some php code for ids and staf to not be equal as other outputs it not work